# How do i retrieve api data using foreach loop in php

Tags: php

This is my data and i want to print the value using decode Json data into array value so please help me out.

```
{
"total_results": 10000,
"page": 1,
"per_page": 15,
"photos": [
    {
        "id": 1687093,
        "width": 3079,
        "height": 4619,
        "url": "https://fingerprintdesigns.studio/",
        "photographer": "Cameron Casey",
        "photographer_id": 455136,
        "src": {
            "original": "https://fingerprintdesigns.studio/",
        },
        "liked": false
    } ] }
```

I want to retrieve `total_results` and `photos->src->original` so how can i do?

Comment: where is this `loop` of which you speak? Are you simply trying to decode the JSON data and extract particular variables? Is what you have shown the FULL response?

Comment: I just want to retrieve all of the data available in JSON format.

Comment: how and where are you retrieving your data from? (from a url, curl, static json file) You can use json_decode to decode the object and then use something like $obj["total_results"], etc to get the data from that decoded object

Comment: I am retrieving data from curl

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to use **json_decode** to converts it into a PHP object:

```
$response = json_decode($url);
```

To retrieve **total_results**:

```
echo $response->total_results;
```

You'll have to loop through **photos** attribute since it's an array of objects:

```
    foreach ($response->photos as $photo) {
        echo $photo->src->original;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one object of photos then you can do as below

```
$obj = '{
 "total_results": 10000,
 "page": 1,
 "per_page": 15,
 "photos": [
 {
    "id": 1687093,
    "width": 3079,
    "height": 4619,
    "url": "https://fingerprintdesigns.studio/",
    "photographer": "Cameron Casey",
    "photographer_id": 455136,
    "src": {
        "original": "https://fingerprintdesigns.studio/"
    },
    "liked": false
} ] }';

// Convert JSON string to Array
$objectArray = json_decode( $obj, true );
print_r($objectArray); // Dump all data of the Array
echo $total_results = $objectArray['total_results']; // Access Array data
echo $originalPhoto = $objectArray['photos'][0]['src']['original'];


// For multiple value
if( is_array( $objectArray['photos'] ) && !empty( $objectArray['photos'] ) ){
foreach ($objectArray['photos'] as $photo) {
    echo $photo['src']['original'];
}
```

}